# Why would you add MIBs to a device/agent?

Tags: snmp, mib

I'm currently learning all the SNMP protocols and attempting to put together a script for querying device information, purely all GET queries.

I've seen a lot of example questions/scripts where people have or can create their own MIBs in a device.

Why would you add an MIB to a device? Surely an Agent would hold all the information possible in the existing MIBs, and creating more would only be redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a new type of device that needs to measure new things, you somehow need to tell the SNMP agent what this is and how to find it, so you write a new MIB for this device and add it to your SNMP agent.